# ATM took in the money after spitting it out

Tags: united-states, credit-card, india, foreign-exchange, atm

I tried to use an Indian bank based (HDFC) Multi currency prepaid card in a Bank of America ATM to withdraw some cash. The ATM did spit it out but took it back in weirdly, looked much like it never dispensed the money. However, the money never got credited back into my card. I approached BofA and they told me that I have to file a dispute in HDFC which I did providing them all the details they needed. It's been two days since the incident. I want to know if there is anything left to do on my part, also how much approximately it will take for my money to get credited back.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As it is international debits, this will take a while. BofA is right, You have to dispute this with Card Issuer, i.e. HDFC. The worst case for me was around 1 month. Keep chasing and sending out reminders every 3-4 days.